# Youtube API search auto-complete

Tags: search, autocomplete, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube API, I'd like to have a search auto-complete feature, just like on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/), when you type into the search input box, it gives you search suggestions.
I've read the docs, but still missing, Is this possible using the API?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Ok I found this URL:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=Query
```

It isn't part of Youtube API, but still works, returns a JSON response.

Comment: That's pretty dang cool... how did you find it, by looking at the network requests for the youtube search?

Comment: we are not getting data in json , it is downoading in .txt file?

Comment: how can we get suggest in json form , from this link .http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=tum+mile

Comment: This doesn't work with AJAX requests because the response lacks CORS headers :(

Comment: It's "The Google Way" :D Sure they have some reasons for that hack
https://codepen.io/vyachkonovalov/pen/XRYpgB?editors=0012

Answer (score 7):

For json just add "client" parameter:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&client=firefox&q=Query

Comment: This is exactly what is needed, made an example based on this http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/oxQQPB

Comment: is it possible to get data response direct in json?? its downloading .txt file

Answer (score 4):

Above all apis are **old** and give *google search suggestion* not **youtube search suggestion**

Use this:

```
https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&gs_ri=youtube&ds=yt&q=faded
```

Extract suggestions using following JS code:

```js
//  data is response of above api
   const data = 'window.google.ac.h(["faded",[["faded",0,[433]],["faded alan walker lyrics",0,[433]],["faded remix",0,[433]],["faded 8d",0,[433]],["faded piano",0,[433]],["faded wheel free fire",0],["faded karaoke",0,[433]],["faded ringtone",0,[433]],["faded instrumental",0,[433]],["faded live",0,[433]],["faded piano tutorial",0,[433]],["faded whatsapp status",0,[433]],["faded dhol cover",0,[433]],["faded dance",0,[433]]],{"k":1,"q":"_sPyvXmmbfcsVtfP4sgjOdKQAvg"}])';

    const searchSuggestions = [];
    data.split('[').forEach((ele, index) => {
      if (!ele.split('"')[1] || index === 1) return;
        return searchSuggestions.push(ele.split('"')[1]);
    });
    console.log(searchSuggestions);
```

Comment: Can `localhost` uses this api? I'm having the `Origin https://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` error.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out  **YouTube AutoComplete Keyword Scraper** . Not really sure of the context the person asking the question wants YouTube auto complete solution for but I thought I would throw this out there.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use JSON:

```
url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=" + i,
        dataType: "jsonp",
```

Answer (score 0):

The official one:

`https://suggestqueries-clients6.youtube.com/complete/search?client=youtube-reduced&hl=en&gs_ri=youtube-reduced&ds=yt&cp=3&gs_id=100&q=Nectar&xhr=t&xssi=t&gl=us`

You can choose country too.

P.S. I searched for Nectar in country US

Answer (score 0):

After making the fetch request

```
const res = await fetch(
    `https://clients1.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&gs_ri=youtube&ds=yt&q=${searchTerm}`,
  );
const str = await res.text();

// const str = window.google.ac.h(["faded",[["faded",0,[433]],["faded alan walker lyrics",0,[433]],["faded remix",0,[433]],["faded 8d",0,[433]],["faded piano",0,[433]],["faded wheel free fire",0],["faded karaoke",0,[433]],["faded ringtone",0,[433]],["faded instrumental",0,[433]],["faded live",0,[433]],["faded piano tutorial",0,[433]],["faded whatsapp status",0,[433]],["faded dhol cover",0,[433]],["faded dance",0,[433]]],{"k":1,"q":"_sPyvXmmbfcsVtfP4sgjOdKQAvg"}])'
```

You can parse the response directly by first cutting the unnecessary pieces

```
const arr = JSON.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf("["), str.indexOf("])") + 1));
```

Here is the shape of the result

```
let suggestionsTuple: [string, number, number[]][] = [];
```

All we need is to filter out the `string`s

```
if (Array.isArray(arr) && Array.isArray(arr.at(1))) {
    suggestionsTuple = arr.at(1);
}

const suggestions = suggestionsTuple.flatMap((suggestion) => suggestion).filter((suggestion) => typeof suggestion === "string"); // ["faded" ,"faded alan walker lyrics", ...]
```