# how to make auto complete search for YouTube iOS API

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have done youtube API integration for iOS, but currently I don't have the auto complete search feature, it is that the user have write to all the words in the textfield to search for a specific video is there any way to to implement auto-complete search through the YouTube API?

Any help would be great

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275365/youtube-api-search-auto-complete
HTH

Comment: There is a spelling suggestion on v2 (previous version): https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Spelling_Suggestions