# how to get youtube `search instead` feature in youtube api version 3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In youtube interface if we search for a term with spelling mistake, Interface provides an option to "search instead" for a similar term. for example
`poovin maarile` search gives you results for `poovin marile`

but while using youtube api version 3, `poovin maarile` gives zero results and `poovin marile` gives 230+ results. But there is no way in the api to get this very closely related term.

I am aware of spelling suggestions feature in version 2 but since version 2 is deprecated I am not interested in using it. Is there something similar for youtube data api version 3?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an official API for this at the moment.

You probably shouldn't rely on this being available in the future, but I think the only alternative at the moment is querying the same URL that YouTube and other pages use.

From another question: [Youtube API search auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275365/youtube-api-search-auto-complete)

A page detailing the query parameters: [Google Autocomplete API](http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/)