# Autocmplete Search on youtube

Tags: search, autocomplete, youtube, google-api

I want to improve my textBox by adding it the autocomplete/suggestions feature.

[image]

I found a bunch of related questions

- [Youtube API search auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275365/youtube-api-search-auto-complete) (Outdated)
- [Google Search autocomplete API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428502/google-search-autocomplete-api)

And this excellent [article](http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/) that actually provide documentation for the API.

My question is simple: **Can I use it? Is it official? If not what alternatives do I got?**

Answer (score 0):

> In the interest of maintaining the integrity of autocomplete as part of Search, we will be restricting unauthorized access to the unpublished autocomplete API as of August 10th, 2015. We want to ensure that users experience autocomplete as it was designed to be used -- as a service closely tied to Search. We believe this provides the best user experience for both services.

[Update on the Autocomplete API](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/07/update-on-autocomplete-api.html)

If an API is not published on an official [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/) portal, you should avoid using it.

Comment: So what about the alternatives?